# How to concat and update pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to concat the dataframe **df1** and **df2** and result the dataframe **df**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "a": 1, "b": 1},
    {"id": 2, "a": 2, "b": 2},
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "a": 5, "b": 5},
    {"id": 3, "a": 6, "b": 6}
])

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "a": 5, "b": 5},
    {"id": 2, "a": 2, "b": 2},
    {"id": 3, "a": 6, "b": 6}
])
```

As can see, the row of same **id** are updated.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Concatenate
2. Remove duplicates

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "a": 1, "b": 1},
    {"id": 2, "a": 2, "b": 2},
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "a": 5, "b": 5},
    {"id": 3, "a": 6, "b": 6}
])

print (pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'),
                  df2.set_index('id')])
       .reset_index()
       .drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last')
       .set_index('id')
       .sort_index())
```

---

Output:

```
    a  b
id      
1   5  5
2   2  2
3   6  6
```